Can't connect using Laravel DB, but works fine using sqlsrv_connect
I am trying to acces a MS SQL server from Laravel by using the following statement:
$codigosgasto = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('select Id_CodigoGasto, Descripcion from dbo_CodigoGasto');

when I run this command I get a connection timeout.

SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select Id_CodigoGasto, Descripcion from dbo_CodigoGasto)

The connection configuration is setup as follows in the .env file:
SECOND_DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
SECOND_DB_HOST=192.168.0.168
SECOND_DB_PORT=1433
SECOND_DB_DATABASE=VFIN1
SECOND_DB_USERNAME=xxxxx
SECOND_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx

and in the database.php connections array:
 'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('SECOND_DB_HOST', '192.168.0.168'),
            'port' => env('SECOND_DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('SECOND_DB_DATABASE', 'VFIN1'),
            'username' => env('SECOND_DB_USERNAME', 'xxxxxx'),
            'password' => env('SECOND_DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx'),
            'charset' => env('SECOND_DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'true'),
        ],

I have tried an alternate connection to the database that works correctly by executing:
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "VFIN1","UID"=>"xxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx","TrustServerCertificate"=>true);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

What am I missing in order to make the laravel DB::connection work?
